# How to Build an Accumulating Either Builder

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I want to build an computational expression for either expressions.
That is simple enough

```
type Result<'TSuccess> = 
| Success of 'TSuccess
| Failure of List<string>

type Foo = {
    a: int
    b: string
    c: bool
}

type EitherBuilder () =
    member this.Bind(x, f) = 
        match x with
        | Success s -> f s
        | Failure f -> Failure f

        member this.Return x = Success x

let either = EitherBuilder ()

let Ok = either {
    let! a = Success 1
    let! b = Success "foo"
    let! c = Success true
    return 
        {
             a = a
             b = b
             c = c
        }
}

let fail1 = either {
    let! a = Success 1
    let! b = Failure ["Oh nose!"]
    let! c = Success true
    return 
        {
             a = a
             b = b
             c = c
        }
    } //returns fail1 = Failure ["Oh nose!"]
```

But in the case of Failures (multiple) I want to accumulate those and return an Failure as below.

```
let fail2 = either {
    let! a = Success 1
    let! b = Failure ["Oh nose!"]
    let! c = Failure ["God damn it, uncle Bob!"]
    return 
        {
             a = a
             b = b
             c = c
        }
    } //should return fail2 = Failure ["Oh nose!"; "God damn it, uncle Bob!"]
```

I have an idea on how to do that by rewriting `Bind` and always returning `Success` (albeit with some additional structure that signifies the accumulated erors). However if I do this then I am missing the stop signal and I always get back the return value (actually not really as I will run into a runtime exception, but in principle)

Comment: I what real life scenario are you planning to use this? Don't you need a Writer Monad instead?

Comment: this is pretty close to the realworld scenario except that `let! a = Success 1` woulr be something like `let! a = someFnReturningAResultWith validationFn someValue`

Comment: It looks to me that you are trying to accumulate validation errors, if so the Writer Monad might be the way to go.

Comment: @Gustavo I am not sure about the Writer. What I really want is the convinience of the `let!` and its usage at a later point AND also the fact that if the Writes something that what has been written shall be return and if nothing has been written than the `return`result should be given back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tomasp is saying one approach is to always provide a value in addition to the failures in order to make `bind` work properly. This is the approach I have been using when dealing with this subject. I would then change the definition of `Result` to, for example, this:

```
type BadCause =
  | Exception of exn
  | Message   of string

type BadTree =
  | Empty
  | Leaf  of BadCause
  | Fork  of BadTree*BadTree

type [<Struct>] Result<'T> = Result of 'T*BadTree
```

This means that a `Result` always has a value whether it's good or bad. The value is good iff the `BadTree` is empty.

The reason I prefer trees over list is that `Bind` will aggregate two separate results that may have subfailures leading to list concatenations.

Some functions that let us create either good or bad value:

```
let rreturn     v       = Result (v, Empty)
let rbad        bv bt   = Result (bv, bt)
let rfailwith   bv msg  = rbad bv (Message msg |> Leaf)
```

Because even bad results need to carry a value in order to make `Bind` work we need to provide the value through `bv` parameter. For types that support `Zero` we can create a convinience method:

```
let inline rfailwithz  msg  = rfailwith LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero<_> msg
```

`Bind` is easy to implement:

```
let rbind (Result (tv, tbt)) uf =
  let (Result (uv, ubt)) = uf tv
  Result (uv, btjoin tbt ubt)
```

That is; we evaluate both results and join the bad trees if needed.

With a computation expression builder the following program:

```
  let r =
    result {
      let! a = rreturn    1
      let! b = rfailwithz "Oh nose!"
      let! c = rfailwithz "God damn it, uncle Bob!"
      return a + b + c
    }

  printfn "%A" r
```

Outputs:

> Result (1,Fork (Leaf (Message "Oh nose!"),Leaf (Message "God damn it, uncle Bob!")))

That is; we get a bad value `1` and the reasons it's bad is because of the two joined error leafs.

I have used this approach when transforming and validating tree structures using composable combinators. It's in my case important to get all validation failure, not just the first. This means that both branches in `Bind` needs to be evaluated but in order to do we must always have a value in order to call `uf` in `Bind t uf`.

As in OP:s own answer I did experiment with `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` but I abandoned for example because the default value of a string is `null` and it usually leads to crashes when invoking `uf`. I did create a map `Type -> empty value` but in my final solution I require a bad value when constructing a bad result.

Hope this helps

Full example:

```
type BadCause =
  | Exception of exn
  | Message   of string

type BadTree =
  | Empty
  | Leaf  of BadCause
  | Fork  of BadTree*BadTree

type [<Struct>] Result<'T> = Result of 'T*BadTree

let (|Good|Bad|) (Result (v, bt)) =
  let ra = ResizeArray 16
  let rec loop bt =
    match bt with
    | Empty         -> ()
    | Leaf  bc      -> ra.Add bc |> ignore
    | Fork  (l, r)  -> loop l; loop r
  loop bt
  if ra.Count = 0 then 
    Good v
  else 
    Bad (ra.ToArray ())

module Result =
  let btjoin      l  r    =
    match l, r with
    | Empty , _     -> r
    | _     , Empty -> l
    | _     , _     -> Fork (l, r)

  let rreturn     v       = Result (v, Empty)
  let rbad        bv bt   = Result (bv, bt)
  let rfailwith   bv msg  = rbad bv (Message msg |> Leaf)

  let inline rfailwithz  msg  = rfailwith LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero<_> msg

  let rbind (Result (tv, tbt)) uf =
    let (Result (uv, ubt)) = uf tv
    Result (uv, btjoin tbt ubt)

  type ResultBuilder () =
    member x.Bind         (t, uf) = rbind t uf
    member x.Return       v       = rreturn v
    member x.ReturnFrom   r       = r : Result<_>

let result = Result.ResultBuilder ()

open Result

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let r =
    result {
      let! a = rreturn    1
      let! b = rfailwithz "Oh nose!"
      let! c = rfailwithz "God damn it, uncle Bob!"
      return a + b + c
    }

  match r with
  | Good v  -> printfn "Good: %A" v
  | Bad  es -> printfn "Bad: %A" es

  0
```

Comment: I like this approach. The only thing would be to sanitize the result at the end. If there was an error your solution nevertheless returns a "valid" object (+ the errors) back. However you might be well advised not to touch the return value - specifically if it contains non-primitive objects. I could do the following `let res = result { ... } |> sanatize` but it would be nice if the builder could do this behind the scene

Comment: Updated the source with Active Patterns in order to pattern match for good/bad results.

Comment: It seems like your tree is isomorphic to a non-empty leaf-labeled tree with labels of type `BadCause option`, but it would make more sense for the tree itself to be optional and each leaf to be non-optional (that is, `type BadTree = Leaf of BadCause | Fork of BadTree*BadTree and Result<'t> = Result of 't * (BadTree option)`.  As it is, your join operation explicitly avoids putting in empty subtrees, but you could prevent that at the type level instead.

Answer (score 4):

I think that what you are trying to do cannot be expressed using monads. The problem is that `Bind` can only call the rest of the computation (which may produce more failures) if it can get a value for the function argument. In your example:

```
let! a = Success 1
let! b = Failure ["Oh nose!"]
let! c = Failure ["God damn it, uncle Bob!"]
```

The binding cannot call the continuation starting with `b` because `Failure ["Oh nose!"]` does not provide a value for `b`. You could use default values and keep errors on the side, but this is changing the structure you are using:

```
type Result<'T> = { Value : 'T; Errors : list<string> }
```

You could write this using applicative functor abstraction where you need to have:

```
Merge  : F<'T1> * F<'T2> -> F<'T1 * 'T2>
Map    : ('T1 -> 'T2) -> M<'T1> -> M<'T2> 
Return : 'T -> M<'T>
```

You can implement all of these in a way that `Merge` accumulates errors (if both arguments represent a failure) and `Map` only applies the computation if there are no values.

There are various ways of encoding applicative functors in F#, but there is no nice syntax for that, so you'll most likely end up using ugly custom operators.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually with the hints of @tomas above I could come with this solution which leaves the data types as they are but creates an stateful builder.

Now the only question that remains for me is this thread safe  - I would assume yes. Maybe someone could confirm?

```
type Result<'TSuccess> = 
    | Success of 'TSuccess
    | Failure of List<string>

type Foo = {
    a: int
    b: string
    c: bool
}

type EitherBuilder (msg) =
    let mutable errors = [msg]
    member this.Bind(x, fn) =
        match x with
        | Success s -> fn s
        | Failure f ->
            errors <- List.concat [errors;f] 
            fn (Unchecked.defaultof<_>)

    member this.Return x =
        if List.length errors = 1 then
            Success x
        else
            Failure errors

let either msg = EitherBuilder (msg)

let Ok = either("OK") {
    let! a = Success 1
    let! b = Success "foo"
    let! c = Success true
    return 
        {
                a = a
                b = b
                c = c
        }
}

let fail1 = either("Fail1") {
    let! a = Success 1
    let! b = Failure ["Oh nose!"]
    let! c = Success true
    return 
        {
                a = a
                b = b
                c = c
        }
} //returns fail1 = Failure ["Fail1"; "Oh nose!"]


let fail2 = either("Fail2") {
    let! a = Success 1
    let! b = Failure ["Oh nose!"]
    let! c = Failure ["God damn it, uncle Bob!"]
    return 
        {
                a = a
                b = b
                c = c
        }
} //should return fail2 = Failure ["Fail2"; "Oh nose!"; "God damn it, uncle Bob!"]
```

Comment: `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` will probably cause crashes as for non-value types the default value is `null` which most F# code don't expect. `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero<_>` is better but requires `inline` and that the type has a static member `Zero`. If you join the lists at the end of `Bind` you don't need a global state.

Comment: I don't get why `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` would be more dangerous than ' `GenericZero`. If there is an failure than I shouldn't access the `return`value anyway. Also `GenericZero` wont work if I do have a non-primitive value

Comment: `GenericZero` works for any type that has `static member Zero` like this: `type X = X of int with static member Zero = X 0` then `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero<X>` returns `X 0` where `Unchecked.defaultOf<X>` returns `null`

Answer (score 1):

We now have applicative computation expressions  with `and!` and MergeSources in the builder.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340678/result-builder-that-accumulates-errors) for a solution