# Result Builder that accumulates Errors

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I'm trying to build `Result Builder` that accumulates `Errors` (in my case they are named `Failures` as I'm following some code from https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/). It's current implementation returns first encountered `Failure` when ideally I'd prefer it to either return `Success` with desired value or a `Failure` with a list of all missing/corrupted values. Unfortunately current implementation it's a bit verbose.

**Boilerplate code**

```
module Rop

type RopResult<'TSuccess, 'TMessage> =
    | Success of 'TSuccess * 'TMessage list
    | Failure of 'TMessage list

/// create a Success with no messages
let succeed x =
    Success (x,[])

/// create a Success with a message
let succeedWithMsg x msg =
    Success (x,[msg])

/// create a Failure with a message
let fail msg =
    Failure [msg]

/// A function that applies either fSuccess or fFailure 
/// depending on the case.
let either fSuccess fFailure = function
    | Success (x,msgs) -> fSuccess (x,msgs) 
    | Failure errors -> fFailure errors 

/// merge messages with a result
let mergeMessages msgs result =
    let fSuccess (x,msgs2) = 
        Success (x, msgs @ msgs2) 
    let fFailure errs = 
        Failure (errs @ msgs) 
    either fSuccess fFailure result

/// given a function that generates a new RopResult
/// apply it only if the result is on the Success branch
/// merge any existing messages with the new result
let bindR f result =
    let fSuccess (x,msgs) =
        f x |> mergeMessages msgs
    let fFailure errs =
        Failure errs
    either fSuccess fFailure result
```

**Builder code**

```
module ResultComputationExpression
    open Rop
    type ResultBuilder() =
        member __.Return(x) = RopResult.Success (x,[])
        member __.Bind(x, f) = bindR f x

        member __.ReturnFrom(x) = x
        member this.Zero() = this.Return ()

        member __.Delay(f) = f
        member __.Run(f) = f()

        member this.While(guard, body) =
            if not (guard()) 
            then this.Zero() 
            else this.Bind( body(), fun () -> 
                this.While(guard, body))  

        member this.TryWith(body, handler) =
            try this.ReturnFrom(body())
            with e -> handler e

        member this.TryFinally(body, compensation) =
            try this.ReturnFrom(body())
            finally compensation() 

        member this.Using(disposable:#System.IDisposable, body) =
            let body' = fun () -> body disposable
            this.TryFinally(body', fun () -> 
                match disposable with 
                    | null -> () 
                    | disp -> disp.Dispose())

        member this.For(sequence:seq<_>, body) =
            this.Using(sequence.GetEnumerator(),fun enum -> 
                this.While(enum.MoveNext, 
                    this.Delay(fun () -> body enum.Current)))

        member this.Combine (a,b) = 
            this.Bind(a, fun () -> b())

    let result = new ResultBuilder()
```

**Use case**

```
let crateFromPrimitive (taskId:int) (title:string) (startTime:DateTime) : RopResult<SomeValue,DomainErrror> =
    result {
        // functions that, at the end, return "RopResult<TaskID,DomainError>" therefore "let! id" is of type "TaskID"
        let! id = taskId |>  RecurringTaskId.create  |> mapMessagesR mapIntErrors 
        // functions that, at the end, return "RopResult<Title,DomainError>" therefore "let! tt" is of type "Title"
        let! tt = title|> Title.create  |> mapMessagesR mapStringErrors 
        // functions that, at the end, return "RopResult<StartTime,DomainError>" therefore "let! st" is of type "StartTime"
        let! st = startTime|> StartTime.create   |> mapMessagesR mapIntErrors 
        

        // "create" returns "RopResult<SomeValue,DomainErrror>",  "let! value" is of type "SomeValue" 
        let! value = create id tt st 

        return value
    }
```

I could possibly split it to first validate `taskId`, `title` and `startTime` and then eventually call `create` but is it possible to do in one go?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604411/2710943) but I have no idea how to translate it to my case or if it's even related.

**UPDATE: Solution**

Just like [brainbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340678/result-builder-that-accumulates-errors/66344238?noredirect=1#comment117286936_66340678) comment and [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344238/2710943) says, `and!` solves my problem. What still troubles me is the idea of automatically de-toupling (namely, when does it happen and on what rules?). In any case, I expect people will be more than able to put two and two together but the working solution for my problem is:

**Builder part**

```
...
member _.MergeSources(result1, result2) =
    match result1, result2 with
    | Success (ok1,msgs1), Success (ok2,msgs2) -> 
        Success ((ok1,ok2),msgs1@msgs2 ) 
    | Failure errs1, Success _ -> Failure errs1
    | Success _, Failure errs2 -> Failure errs2
    | Failure errs1, Failure errs2 -> Failure (errs1 @ errs2)   // accumulate errors
...
```

**Use Case**

```
let crateFromPrimitive taskId title startTime duration category description (subtasks:string list option) (repeatFormat:RepeatFormat option) =
    result {

        let strintToSubTask = (Subtask.create >> (mapMessagesR mapStringErrors)) 
        let sListToSubtaskList value =  List.map strintToSubTask value
                                          |> RopResultHelpers.sequence

        let! id = RecurringTaskId.create taskId |> mapMessagesR mapIntErrors
        and! tt = Title.create title  |> mapMessagesR mapStringErrors
        and! st = StartTime.create startTime  |> mapMessagesR mapIntErrors
        and! dur = Duration.create duration  |> mapMessagesR mapIntErrors
        and! cat = Category.create category  |> mapMessagesR mapStringErrors
        and! desc = Description.create description  |> mapMessagesR mapStringErrors
        and! subtOption = someOrNone sListToSubtaskList subtasks |> RopResultHelpers.fromOptionToSuccess 
        //let! value = create id tt st dur cat desc subtOption repeatFormat

        return! create id tt st dur cat desc subtOption repeatFormat
    }
```

Comment: Question: Why does the success case have a list of messages? Are these intended to be "warnings" rather than outright errors? Suggestion: I assume that `id`, `tt`, and `st` in your use case are independent from each other? If so, you might want to look into the [new applicative syntax](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5/#applicative-computation-expressions) (`and!`) in F# 5, rather than `let!`.

Comment: That final link is related to your question. As is also @tomasp's following answer too. I thought this is what you were trying in this question. In Scott's link if you read on you will see that this is not monadic but applicative, as both the aforementioned answers discuss. We did not have applicative computational expressions when those answers were created but we do now and brian berns has provided an excellent answer.

Comment: Yes, ``and!`` is a solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I searched around a bit and didn't find any validators that use the new `and!` syntax and accumulate errors, so I decided to write a quick one myself. I think this does what you want, and is much simpler. Note that I'm using `Result<_, List<_>>` to accumulate a list of errors, rather than creating a new type.

```
type AccumValidationBuilder() =

    member _.BindReturn(result, f) =
        result |> Result.map f

    member _.MergeSources(result1, result2) =
        match result1, result2 with
            | Ok ok1, Ok ok2 -> Ok (ok1, ok2)   // compiler will automatically de-tuple these - very cool!
            | Error errs1, Ok _ -> Error errs1
            | Ok _, Error errs2 -> Error errs2
            | Error errs1, Error errs2 -> Error (errs1 @ errs2)   // accumulate errors

let accValid = AccumValidationBuilder()
```

And here it is in action:

```
let validateInt (str : string) =
    match Int32.TryParse(str) with
        | true, n -> Ok n
        | _ -> Error [ str ]

let test str1 str2 str3 =
    let result =
        accValid {
            let! n1 = validateInt str1
            and! n2 = validateInt str2
            and! n3 = validateInt str3
            return n1 + n2 + n3
        }
    printfn "Result : %A" result

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    test "1" "2" "3"        // output: Ok 6
    test "1" "red" "blue"   // output: Error [ "red"; "blue" ]
    0
```

Comment: Part ``| Ok ok1, Ok ok2 -> Ok (ok1, ok2)   // compiler will automatically de-tuple these - very cool!`` Is this de-tupling some default compilers behaviour or is it just some special case for ``Ok`` type? In my case ``RopResult.Success`` is of type ``Success of 'TSuccess * 'TMessage list``. Will ``Success (ok1,msgs1), Success (ok2,msgs2) -> Success ((ok1,ok2),msgs1@msgs2 )`` still be somehow de-tupled? I can't find any information about it in docs.

Comment: The de-tupling is part of the syntactic sugar provided by the compiler as part of the new support for `MergeSources` in a computation builder.