# Implementing let! ... and! ... in a custom Computation Expression

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I want to add support to my Computation Expression builder for this construct:

```ml
let f = 
  foo {
    let! x =
      foo {
        return 1
      }
    and! y =
      foo {
        return 2
      }

    return x + y
  }
```

The compiler says I must implement either `Bind2` or `MergeSource`. However, I cannot find them in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions#built-in-computation-expressions).

What signatures should these have? Can you give a simple example?

Comment: Check this out: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5-preview-1/#applicative-computation-expressions

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the RFC is dead in the announcement blog; here is the correct address: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/FSharp-5.0/FS-1063-support-letbang-andbang-for-applicative-functors.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple builder that works with your example:

```ml
type Foo<'t> = MkFoo of 't

type FooBuilder() =
    member _.Bind(MkFoo x, f) = f x
    member _.Return(x) = MkFoo x
    member _.MergeSources(MkFoo x, MkFoo y) = MkFoo (x, y)

let foo = FooBuilder()

let f =
    foo {
        let! x = foo { return 1 }
        and! y = foo { return 2 }
        return x + y
    }
printfn "%A" f   // output: MkFoo 3
```

The purpose of `MergeSources` is to create a tuple of results that will be automatically de-tupled by the compiler. You might also find [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-50#applicative-computation-expressions) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340678/result-builder-that-accumulates-errors/66344238) useful.