# F# - Nested types

Tags: validation, functional-programming, f#

I'm trying to understand functional programming using F# and to do so I started small project, but I run in following issue and can't seem to find any elegant solution for it.
I created `Validation<'a>` which is pretty much specialized F# Result: `Result<'a, Error list>` which helps me to handle validation results.

I have two functions that perform some validation both with signatures:

```
'a -> Validation<'b>
```

There is also a third function that consumes validated arguments with signature:

```
'a -> 'b -> Validation<'c>
```

What I would like to achieve is to:

1. Validate argument 'a
2. If validation of argument 'a passes, validate argument 'b
3. If validation of argument 'b passes, provide arguments 'a and 'b to final function

Thus far I used apply function to achieve such behaviour, but when I try to use it in this case the result type is nested Validation `Validation<Validation<'c>>`, since final function itself returns Validation. I would like to get rid of one of validations, so that result type would be `Validation<'c>`. I tried to experiment with bind and variants of lift functions which I found [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/#the-liftn-family-of-functions), but result remains the same. Is nested match an only option here?

**Edit #1**: Here is a simplified code that I currently have:

Here are types that handle validation:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type Error = {
    Message: string
    Code: int
}
    
type Validation<'a> =
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of Error list

let apply elevatedFunction elevatedValue =
    match elevatedFunction, elevatedValue with
    | Success func, Success value -> Success (func value)
    | Success _, Failure errors -> Failure errors
    | Failure errors, Success _ -> Failure errors
    | Failure currentErrors, Failure newErrors -> Failure (currentErrors@newErrors)

let (<*>) = apply
```

Problematic function is this one:

```ml
let formatReport (unvalidatedLanguageName: string) (unvalidatedReport: UnvalidatedReport): Validation<Validation<string>> =
    Success formatReportAsText
    <*> languageTranslatorFor unvalidatedLanguageName
    <*> reportFrom unvalidatedReport
```

Validation functions:

```
let languageTranslatorFor (unvalidatedLanguageName: string): Validation<Entry -> string> = ...

let reportFrom (unvalidatedReport: UnvalidatedReport): Validation<Report> = ...
```

Function that consumes validation arguments:

```
let formatReportAsText (languageTranslator: Entry -> string) (report: Report): Validation<string> = ...
```

**Edit #2**: I attempted to use [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344238/344223) provided by @brianberns and implemented computation expression for Validation<'a> type:

```ml
// Validation<'a> -> Validation<'b> -> Validation<'a * 'b>
let zip firstValidation secondValidation =
    match firstValidation, secondValidation with
    | Success firstValue, Success secondValue -> Success(firstValue, secondValue)
    | Failure errors, Success _ -> Failure errors
    | Success _, Failure errors -> Failure errors
    | Failure firstErrors, Failure secondErrors -> Failure (firstErrors @ secondErrors)

// Validation<'a> -> ('a -> 'b) -> Validation<'b>
let map elevatedValue func =
    match elevatedValue with
    | Success value -> Success(func value)
    | Failure validationErrors -> Failure validationErrors

type MergeValidationBuilder() =
    member _.BindReturn(validation: Validation<'a>, func) = Validation.map validation func
        
    member _.MergeSources(validation1, validation2) = Validation.zip validation1 validation2
    
let validate = MergeValidationBuilder()
```

and use it as such:

```ml
let formatReport (unvalidatedLanguageName: string) (unvalidatedReport: UnvalidatedReport): Validation<Validation<string>> =
    validate = {
        let! translator = languageTranslatorFor unvalidatedLanguageName
        and! report = reportFrom unvalidatedReport

        return formatReportAsText translator report
    }
```

While computation expression is definitely nicer to read the end result remains exactly the same [Validation<Validation>] due to fact that "formatReportAsText" function also returns result wrapped in Validation.
To somewhat merge stacked validations I used below function, but it seems clunky to me:

```ml
// Validation<Validation<'a>> -> Validation<'a>
let merge (nestedValidation: Validation<Validation<'a>>): Validation<'a> =
    match nestedValidation with
    | Success innerValidation ->
        match innerValidation with
        | Success value -> Success value
        | Failure innerErrors -> Failure innerErrors
    | Failure outerErrors -> Failure outerErrors
```

**Edit #3:** After addition of "ReturnFrom" function to validation computation expression to flatten nested validations the validation function works as intended.

```ml
member _.ReturnFrom(validation) = validation
```

The final version of validation function that uses computation expression is:

```ml
let formatReport (unvalidatedLanguageName: string) (unvalidatedReport: UnvalidatedReport): Validation<string> =
    validate = {
        let! translator = languageTranslatorFor unvalidatedLanguageName
        and! report = reportFrom unvalidatedReport

        return! formatReportAsText translator report
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you currently have?

Comment: [I consider validation a solved problem in FP](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/12/14/validation-a-solved-problem), but if (like @brianberns requests) you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'll be happy to help with the specifics.

Comment: Based on what you've provided so far, I think this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344238/344223) is probably what you're looking for. It's a computation expression builder that uses the new `and!` syntax to accumulate validation errors. (You can add a `Bind` method if you really want to serialize validation instead of doing them in parallel.)

Comment: What you need is `Result.bind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `formatReportAsText` returns a validated string (rather than a plain string), you should use `return!` instead of `return` at the end of your computation expression:

```ml
return! formatReportAsText translator report
```

This is equivalent to:

```ml
let! value = formatReportAsText translator report   // value is a string
return value
```

If I understand your code correctly, the type of the computation expression will then be `Validation<string>` instead of `Validation<Validation<string>>`.

Note that you'll need a `ReturnFrom` method on your builder to make `return!` work:

```ml
member __.ReturnFrom(value) = value
```

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions) for details.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I still seem to have a hard time to understand computation expressions properly. After addition of ReturnFrom and using return! the function works perfectly.

Comment: Computation expressions are powerful but can be mind-bending. Glad you got yours working. Please accept the answer if you are using it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to skin that cat, but central to most of them is that whenever you encounter a nested container like `Validation<Validation<string>>`, you'll need some way to 'flatten' the nesting. For a type like `Validation`, that's easy:

```
// Validation<Validation<'a>> -> Validation<'a>
let join = function
    | Success x -> x
    | Failure errors -> Failure errors
```

You might also choose to call this function `flatten`, but it's often called `join`.

You may also find a `map` function useful. This one is also easy:

```
// ('a -> 'b) -> Validation<'a> -> Validation<'b>
let map f = function
    | Success x -> Success (f x)
    | Failure errors -> Failure errors
```

Such a `map` function makes `Validation` a [functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/22/functors).

When you have both `map` and `join`, you can *always* implement a method usually known as `bind`:

```
// ('a -> Validation<'b>) -> Validation<'a> -> Validation<'b>
let bind f = map f >> join
```

The ability to flatten or `join` a nested container is what makes it a monad. While it's a word surrounded by mystique and awe, it's really just that: it's a functor you can flatten.

Usually, however, `join` and `bind` are defined the other way around:

```
let bind f = function
    | Success x -> f x
    | Failure errors -> Failure errors

let join x = bind id x
```

With `join` you can adjust the problematic function by flattening the nested container:

```
// string -> UnvalidatedReport -> Validation<string>
let formatReport (unvalidatedLanguageName: string) (unvalidatedReport: UnvalidatedReport) =
    Success formatReportAsText
    <*> languageTranslatorFor unvalidatedLanguageName
    <*> reportFrom unvalidatedReport
    |> join
```

That's not how I'd do it, however. While such combinator gymnastics can be fun, they' aren't always the most readable solution.

## Computation expression

I'd prefer defining a [Computation Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions), which can minimally be done like this:

```
type ValidationBuilder () =
    member _.Bind (x, f) = bind f x
    member _.ReturnFrom x = x

let validate = ValidationBuilder ()
```

This now enables you to write the desired function like this:

```
// string -> UnvalidatedReport -> Validation<string>
let formatReport (unvalidatedLanguageName: string) (unvalidatedReport: UnvalidatedReport) =
    validate {
        let! l = languageTranslatorFor unvalidatedLanguageName
        let! r = reportFrom unvalidatedReport
        return! formatReportAsText l r
    }
```

The problem with this version, however, is that it doesn't use the `apply` function to append to errors together. In other words, it'll short-circuit on the first error it encounters.

In order to support collecting errors without short-circuiting, you're going to need a computation builder that supports [applicative functors](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/10/01/applicative-functors), like @brianberns pointed to. You can also see an example [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/12/28/an-f-demo-of-validation-with-partial-data-round-trip).

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer Mark. ReturnFrom seem to be the part that I was missing. I have a few questions regarding what you wrote: Is case where both inner and outer validations both failed and join would discard inner validation errors possible? Secondly, the monad. As you said this is a word surrounded by mystery and do I understand correctly, that it is a "container" designed to handle side effects [such as Async<'a>]?

Comment: @Bremewoord To you first question, I think you'll learn best by discovering the answer yourself: Try to create a `Validation<Validation<'a>` value where, as you say, both the inner and outer value is a `Failure`. What do you learn? As to the second question, the word _container_ offers a mental model for a functor, but [theoretically, it goes deeper than that](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/01/14/functors-are-containers/). It doesn't, however, have to be about side effects. List and Maybe, for example, don't model side effects.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you are getting into a fairly advanced area of F# - but the most practical solution would be to use a computation builder as referenced in the previous answer linked by @brianberns in the comment.

If you wanted to stick to the somewhat simpler approach based on combinators, you could do this using the following functions:

```
val merge : Validation<'a> -> Validation<'b> -> Validation<'a * 'b>
val bind : ('a -> Validation<'b>) -> Validation<'a> -> Validation<'b>
```

Merge is a function that takes two possibly validated values and produces a new one that combines the errors (as your original apply function). The Bind function applies a function to a validated value and collapses the "nested" validation in the result. They can be implemented as:

```
let merge elevatedValue1 elevatedValue2 = 
    match elevatedValue1, elevatedValue2 with 
    | Success v1, Success v2 -> Success (v1, v2)
    | Success _, Failure errors -> Failure errors
    | Failure errors, Success _ -> Failure errors
    | Failure e1, Failure e2 -> Failure (e1 @ e2)

let bind f elevatedValue =
    match elevatedValue with
    | Success value -> 
        match f value with 
        | Success value -> Success value
        | Failure e -> Failure e
    | Failure e -> Failure e
```

Thanks to `merge`, you can validate the two inputs and (possibly) merge the errors. Thanks to `bind`, you can then continue the computation and handle the fact that the rest of it may also fail. You can write your composed function as:

```
let formatReport (unvalidatedLanguageName: string) 
      (unvalidatedReport: UnvalidatedReport): Validation<string> =
  merge 
    (languageTranslatorFor unvalidatedLanguageName)
    (reportFrom unvalidatedReport)
  |> bind formatReportAsText
```